# mdmsoft/yii2-admin routes not working advanced template

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-rbac

i'm trying to implement  [mdmsoft/yii2-admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin) with advanced template with [this pull request](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/pull/309)
but when i try add route to menu get error "Route "x" not found."
if i try force add route via database the menu show an empty array.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to create one inside `config/main.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [ 
            'test/' => site(ControllerName)/test(actionName),
        ]
];
```

Let me know was this helpful or not.